# Replace the html of an element with the content of an external template in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive which is a sidebar in my shell page that will change accordingly whenever a new route is hit, and will populate itself with the sub menu items relevant to that parent route. I have 4 different menus which are external templates and i want the contents of those html files to replace the menu, the link function of my directive looks like this so far:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, current, previous) {
                   element.html('<div ng-include=\'enterprisesMenu.html\'></div>');
                });
      };
```

But the element is not updating, however when i use inline templates the elements updates according, but because each template is complex i prefer not to have that html inside my directive, I've also tried `element.html('<div ng-include src=\'enterprisesMenu.html\'></div>');`

Any ideas?

Comment: Not 100% on topic, but your question sounds like you should read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Comment: Thanks, yea I've already read that, kinda difficult integrating it into your practice though. What would be a more angular way of achieving this functionality in your opinion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$compile`:

```
element.html($compile('<div ng-include=\'enterprisesMenu.html\'></div>')
(scope));
```

Comment: Thanks that almost did the trick, but I had to put double quotes around the template, ended up like this: `element.html($compile('<div ng-include="\'enterprisesMenu.html\'"></div>')(scope));`

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this result by dynamically ng-including the desired template. For instance:

HTML:

```
<div class="your-sidebar" ng-controller="SidebarCtrl">
    <div ng-include="sidebar.url" ></div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller("SidebarCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.sidebar = {
        url: "initial-url"
    };
    $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function(event, current, previous) {
        // decide potentially new value for $scope.sidebar.url
        $scope.sidebar.url = newValueCalculatedAbove;
    });
});
```

This solution does not require a directive, only an extra controller. It can be done with directive too, the HTML above is the template of the directive and the JS code the *controller* (no link function required).

Comment: Thanks. Yea I was contemplating whether to use a controller or a directive, controller seemed simpler from the outset as well, but somehow I was under the impression directives are the way to go. Which approach is more angular? The directive or controller?

Comment: It doesn't really matter for this case, but I would go for the directive. See last paragraph of answer; the code is the same, you would only have to wrap it in a directive declaration. In any case I would avoid using `$compile` since there is a simpler alternative - the `ng-include` (but this is a personal opinion).